# Ubuntu 21.04 LTS Server is getting choked

Tags: server, raid, syslinux

I am new to Linux, We have Lenovo SR650 Server 64 Gb Ram, 2 Processor silver and have Install Samsung M.2 (NVMe)  Evo 970 Pro plus (1 TB) with RAID 10  which we have installed on RAID Controller PCI 3.0 of High Point technology SSD7103 Card.

I have installed Ubuntu 21.04 Server on it however after some time the server it getting choked and I am not able access it even I cannot ping the IP, unless or until I hard reboot the server it will not get back.

Appreciate if any help provided.

Comment: Is there nothing on the console when this happens?  If there are any other PCIe devices in the system, try removing them.

Comment: What do you mean by "chocked"?  Are there logs? Did you try `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` ? Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: I have contact the manufacturer they have not release the driver for Ubuntu 21 version so I cannot installed driver for Hardware, however I can make RAID 10 from LVM.